# how to create a blazor app in visual studio 2015?

Tags: c#, blazor

I am new to this topic. I want to create a blazer app. But visual studio 2015 does not offer the blazor templet.
Does anyone know the solution to this?

I tried to find the blazor templet but couldn't.

Comment: Use a newer version of Visual Studio.  2015 is far too old to support a .NET (Core) version that includes Blazor, VS2015 barely supported .NET Core 1.0. Blazor wasn't released until .NET Core 3.0, so unlikely to be supported by any version of Visual Studo prior to 16.3.  Is there a reason you are using such an old version of VS?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible.  VS 2015 isn't a time machine.  It doesn't know about the future.